# Problema de lógica com Progress Circle

Tags: wpf, lógica

Tenho um progress circle no meu projeto wpf, estou usando uma classe para converter o valor 360 em 100, para ficar como se fosse 100%, mas tenho um problema, eu recebo um tempo X, e os 100% do circulo tem que ser preenchido no tempo X; Se X=120 segundos, então o círculo tem que ser preenchido em 120 segundos. Não sei como fazer. Eu uso um TimeSpan para fazer a contagem do tempo:

```
public partial class TempoEtapa : UserControl
{

    public static DispatcherTimer Temporizador  = new DispatcherTimer();

    public TempoEtapa()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Temporizador.Tick += new EventHandler(DispatcherTimer_Tick);
        Temporizador.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    }

    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Valor = 0;

        if (Value == 120)
        {
            Valor = 0;
        }
        else
        {
           Valor = Value + 1;
        }

        SetValue(ValueProperty, Valor);
    }
```

//Código que converte 360 em 100

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(double))]
public class Valor : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)((int)value * 0.01) * 360;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)((double)value / 360) * 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução. Parei de usar o Conversor; usando os 360° do circulo eu apenas divido 360 por X e incremento o valor do ângulo a partir desse resultado.